# Split, remove whitespace, and explode string in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, explode

I am currently working on web scraping data for college basketball which reflects the current schedule. The site that I am scraping this data has it formatted in a strange manner so I am trying to split things up to make sense for my purposes.

The data comes in like this:

| Matchup | Time |
| --- | --- |
| #15 Marquette at #12 Creighton | 8:30 PM |
| #20 Iowa State at #10 Texas | 9:00 PM |
| #3 Tennessee at #30 Texas A&M | 7:00 PM |

In a perfect scenario, I am wanting to split the data at the 'at' instance so I can differentiate between Home and Away, remove the team rank as it is not necessary, ensure all whitespaces are removed from split string for cleanliness, and have 1 time stated instead of 2 after the explode.

Example design of what I am trying to achieve:

| Matchup | Time |
| --- | --- |
| Marquette | 8:30 PM |
| Creighton |  |
| Iowa State | 9:00 PM |
| Texas |  |
| Tennessee | 7:00 PM |
| Texas A&M |  |

I have done a split like this:

```
df['Matchup'] = df['Matchup'].str.split(' at ', n=1, expand=False)
```

But the whitespaces still look to be present after that.
I was then doing the explode which is getting me close to a final result, except it has the duplicate times and the string has still yet to be fully formatted.

```
df = df.explode('Matchup')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative approach using [`pandas.Series.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```py
df[['Away', 'Home']] = df['Matchup'].str.split(' at ', n=1, expand=True)
df['Away'] = df['Away'].str.replace(r'#\d+ ','').str.strip()
df['Home'] = df['Home'].str.replace(r'#\d+ ','').str.strip()

df = df.drop('Matchup', axis=1)[['Away', 'Home', 'Time']]
print(df)
```

---

```
         Away       Home     Time
0   Marquette  Creighton  8:30 PM
1  Iowa State      Texas  9:00 PM
2   Tennessee  Texas A&M  7:00 PM
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Next steps were to label Home and Away and this helps just simplify this process.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
x = df['Matchup'].str.extract(r'#\d+\s*(.*?)\s*at\s*#\d+\s*(.*)')

x[2], x[3] = df['Time'], ''
x[0] = x[[0, 1]].agg(list, axis=1)
x[1] = x[[2, 3]].agg(list, axis=1)

print(x[[0, 1]].explode([0, 1]).rename(columns={0:'Matchup', 1:'Time'}))
```

Prints:

```
      Matchup     Time
0   Marquette  8:30 PM
0   Creighton         
1  Iowa State  9:00 PM
1       Texas         
2   Tennessee  7:00 PM
2   Texas A&M
```

Comment: When I try this with my data, my Matchup strings are just turning into NaN. Is there a package/module that I need to import for regex?

Comment: @Link Try it with updated regex: `#\d+\s*(.*?)\s*at\s*#\d+\s*(.*)`